# Can RNA assisted protein folding be performed computationally?

Tags: simulation, bioinformatics

I am looking for tools/ softwares to perform protein folding in presence of its RNA partner. Part of my protein is disordered and I suspect that it will take up structure while interacting with its RNA partner. Till now I did not find any literature where computational tools like MD has been implemented to check for such folding.

If anyone has come across any literature or have performed such studies, can you kindly help me how to proceed with it?

Thanking You,
Dolly

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic on stackoverflow (no specific programing problem, not reproducible, ..) when you are looking for software, try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have added the question at the given site.

Comment: You should goto biostars.